# Переход на другую страницу сайта wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button

У меня есть сайт созданный на wordpress и есть кнопка на публикации. Есть такой url: https://highthand.com/176-2/ и мне нужно чтобы когда я нажимаю на кнопку я переходил на другой сайт и url выглядела так : https://getsafe.cloud/176-2/ то есть в url добавлялся ключ той страницы с которой совершался переход при этом должно отображаться содержимое страницы getsafe.cloud. Я использую плагин max button. Как это можно реализовать? Может как то с помощью js или плагин какой то есть. Всё облазил ничего толком не нашёл. Заранее спасибо, буду благодарен за любую помощь. Ключ имеется ввиду https://highthand.com/176-2/ это 176-2, я могу прописать ссылку на https://getsafe.cloud/176-2, ну тогда я получаю ошибку, что страница не найдена , а мне нужно чтобы отображалось содержимое сайта getsafe.cloud при этом url выглядел так https://getsafe.cloud/176-2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переход по кнопке на ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461319/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Перестаньте пересоздавать один и тот же вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае можете на втором сайте создать папку **176-2**, в ней файл **index.html** и в нём перенаправление:

```js
location.href = '/';
```

Но тогда в адресной строке увидите 'https://getsafe.cloud'. Чтобы такого не было, есть другой вариант - в файле **index.html** такое содержимое:

```html
<iframe src='https://getsafe.cloud' width=100% height=100%></iframe>
```